# What is LoggerExtension Args Parameter and how to integrate with Application insights?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, ilogger

I thought using args parameter i will see a new custom dimension under customDimensions in Azure Application insights but it is not working for me. I cannot find any good information about how to use this parameter. What is it for and where in App insights is the information can be found?

I simply passed an array of strings but no where this object can be found in AI.

```
//
        // Summary:
        //     Formats and writes an error log message.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   logger:
        //     The Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger to write to.
        //
        //   exception:
        //     The exception to log.
        //
        //   message:
        //     Format string of the log message in message template format. Example:
        //     "User {User} logged in from {Address}"
        //
        //   args:
        //     An object array that contains zero or more objects to format.
        public static void LogError(this ILogger logger, Exception exception, string message, params object[] args)
        {
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, exception, message, args);
        }
```

Comment: Args Parameter is the java related parameter which will be used as a string in spring boot before the -Jar application. Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-arguments#spring-boot-via-docker-entry-point)

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT thanks for that but why is it not documented anywhere i dont understand. I should be clearly stated even in the source code comment. It causes a lot of confusions

Comment: Does the link provided by me worked for you to make it as a documented we can raise a feature request by using this [link](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/8849e04d-1325-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f09d0?category_id=162018)

Comment: @Emil it will show up as customDimensions but only if you add placeholders to the message. Can you post an example of your line that includes the `arg` argument?

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT I totally don't understand the relation to the java stuff in this scenario.

Comment: @PeterBons yes i found out how to add as customDimensions later but it is totally different way, nothing to do with args. so Args seems to be useless if it is planned for java or something else, not sure but doesnt work for .net Core.

Comment: @Emil no, args is not useless, see my answer

Answer (score 5):

> I thought using args parameter i will see a new custom dimension under customDimensions in Azure Application insights

It does, but only if you supply a [message template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#log-message-template). For example, the following won't work:

```cs
logger.LogError(ex, "Error occured", "a", "simple", "string");
```

but this will:

```cs
logger.LogError(ex, "Error occured {PropA} {PropB} {PropC}", "a", "simple", "string");
```

The last line will result in three properties (named PropA, PropB and PropC) in the `customDimensions` field of the generated telemetry.